# KafkaSource connection to Confluent Kafka (with SSL & SchemaRegistry)

Tags: python, ssl, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python, mlrun

I tried to connect to Confluent Kafka with KafkaSource (from MLRun) and I used historically this easy code:

```
# code with usage 'kafka-python>=2.0.2'
from kafka import KafkaProducer, KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'ak47-data.v1',
    bootstrap_servers =[
        'cpkafka01.eu.prod:9092', 
        'cpkafka02.eu.prod:9092', 
        'cpkafka03.eu.prod:9092'
    ],
    client_id='test',
    auto_offset_reset='earliest',
    sasl_mechanism="SCRAM-SHA-256",
    sasl_plain_password="***********",
    sasl_plain_username="***********",
    security_protocol='SASL_SSL',
    ssl_cafile="/v3io/bigdata/rootca.crt",
    ssl_certfile=None,
    ssl_keyfile=None)

# print first topic
for message in consumer:
    print ("%s:%d:%d: key=%s value=%s" % (message.topic, message.partition,
                                          message.offset, message.key, message.value))
    break
```

How to rewrite this code with KafkaSource usage?

Comment: Which MLRun version do you use?

Comment: I am using the last version MLRun>=1.1.2 (but also 1.2.0-rc13)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me share function code for KafkaSource (for MLRun>=1.1.0). You can specific certificate (see rootca.crt) and list of kafka topics also.

```
from mlrun.datastore.sources import KafkaSource

# certificate
with open('/v3io/bigdata/rootca.crt') as x: 
    caCert = x.read()

# definition of KafkaSource
kafka_source = KafkaSource(
    brokers=['cpkafka01.eu.prod:9092', 
    'cpkafka02.eu.prod:9092', 
    'cpkafka03.eu.prod:9092'],
    topics=["ak47-data.v1"],
    initial_offset="earliest",
    group="test",
    attributes={"sasl" : {
                  "enable": True,
                  "password" : "******",
                  "user" : "*******",
                  "handshake" : True,
                  "mechanism" : "SCRAM-SHA-256"},
                "tls" : {
                  "enable": True,
                  "insecureSkipVerify" : False
                },            
               "caCert" : caCert}
)
```